# Xamarin forms View difference in android & iOS

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

There is a difference of view in android & iOS. Please help me understand if this is the default platform behavior?

**Code:**

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition
  Height="Auto" />
<RowDefinition
  Height="Auto" />
<RowDefinition
  Height="Auto" />  
</Grid.RowDefinitions>  
<Label grid.row="0" Text={Binding FirstName}/>
<Label grid.row="1" Text={Binding LastName}/>
<Label grid.row="2" Text={Binding Email}/>                                                      
</Grid>
```

If LastName is empty in android, it leaves blank space in grid no 2 as below

[image: Andoid UI]

Whereas in iOS if LastName is empty, the UI adjusts as below

[image: iOS UI]

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: This is how the platform is designed.On Android, if your text is empty, it seems still holds the position, whereas on ios, if text is empty, the other views calculate the position from zero.You could test on each platform.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a StackLayout in such situations. In my experience, it will automatically resize if the label is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It will leave space irrespective of the content in the variable. Try using a 'Not Null Converter' to solve your issue.

```
public class IsNotNullConverter : IValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object? value, Type? targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo? culture) => !ConvertInternal(value);

        internal static bool ConvertInternal(object? value) =>
        value == null || (value is string str && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str));

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
}
```

How to use it in your code:
`<Label grid.row="1" Text={Binding LastName} IsVisibile="{Binding LastName, Converter="{x:StaticResource NotNullConverter}"}"/>`